# Response has nothing in it

Tags: scrapy

I have been following the scrapy tutorial trying to create a very simple web scraper for warframe.market.  I have about a year of coding experience from school, but no python experience.  I simply want to get the price of an item from the website.  I used the following to scrape the page:

```
scrapy shell "https://warframe.market/items/hydroid_prime_set"
```

then I inspected the web page to find the individual elements that I am trying to scrape.  I used this command to try to view the results I wanted:

```
response.css("div.order-row.d-flex.col-12").extract()
```

This did not work, so I used `view(response)` to see what I had scraped, and my cmd just waits endlessly at this point.

Is HTTPS stopping me from scraping? Am I selecting the wrong css in my response? Is the webpage too big?  Could someone please show me where I went wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The response isn't empty, but it's rendered using javascript (you can validate it inspecting the `response.body`), for example try this in the shell:

```
import json
data = json.loads(response.css('#application-state::text').extract_first())
for order in data.get('payload',{}).get('orders', []):
    print '"{}" price: {}'.format(order.get('platinum'), 
                                  order.get('user',{}).get('ingame_name'))
```